# ffmpeg compiling on MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)

Tags: compilation, ffmpeg

i want to compile ffmpeg on windows **MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)** because i want to use it in **wamp server 2** which is compiled using the **same compiler** however am currently at a loss of how to do this as there are no visual studio solution files. I know it is possible because people have compiled dlls but i cant seem to find just how they did it . There are also some precompiled dlls here but they are incompatible with my php version 5.38. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFMPEG does not compile natively under MSVC.  You'll need to compile it under mingw or download pre-built libs/dlls from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

You will be able to compile your own apps against the link libraries with MSVC though.