# How do you compile FFmpeg for Windows (x86 and x64) using GCC/Clang for Windows?

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg, clang

There's an in passing mention to GCC/Clang in the [FFmpeg compiling guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

> - If using `GCC/Clang`, consider adding `-march=native` to `--extra-cflags` to make slightly better use of your hardware.
>     Alternatively, for a more general solution, examine the `--arch` and
>     `--cpu` options. Gains are variable, and usually quite small. However,
>     this is usually even more safe than the above, and is thus listed
>     here.

I found a guide to compile [FFmpeg 4.0 for Android](https://medium.com/@ilja.kosynkin/building-ffmpeg-4-0-for-android-with-clang-642e4911c31e), for example, but none devoted to Windows builds.

I'm interested in detailed answers explaining how you get to compile FFmpeg Windows builds for x86 and x64 using GCC/Clang for Windows or a successfully tested guide to it (which I didn't find).

Please include the way you must install every software needed. Needless to say, any other useful information should be in comments.

Comment: Just use https://github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite or examine it if you want to emulate it.

Comment: I'm aware of alvarado's and rdp's build scripts, but they don't use Clang at all.

Comment: Your title and body mention GCC/Clang and those scripts use GCC. I don't know if there's an active GCC port which can emit LLVM IR. Probably edit out GCC if you only want Clang.

Comment: I'm not even sure if GCC/Clang has been (can be) done. I'll suppose who wrote the note knew something we don't and it's undocumented or lost somewhere. If someone has done it, it would be nice of them sharing it here. Only Clang would be even more interesting (and a different question), but [they](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358478/is-it-possible-to-build-ffmpeg-x64-on-windows) [say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179807/ffmpeg-compiling-on-msvc9-visual-c-2008) that "documented" ways to compile FFmpeg (i.e. VS) are simply fake, so only Clang... Let's begin with simplest.

Comment: GCC and Clang are two different projects. Clang is used with LLVM. GCC is used standalone.

Comment: I understood the sentence in the documentation as if there existed a plugin or extension that allowed Clang to use GCC as back end instead of LLVM. I didn't think it might be a disjunctive.